# Does $a < b \implies a^{1/3} < b^{1/3}$

Tags: inequality

given $a < b$

is $a^{1/3} < b^{1/3}$ true?

i think it is, because we can just raise them both by power of 3 and we will get to the given statement, is that correct?

Comment: The Stack Exchange software has a thing in it that rejects very short posts for being "of low quality". This is not appropriate for math.stackexchange posts, and you were right to ignore it.

Comment: You have to know that "raising to the power 3" preserves inequalities. That is, you need to know $x^3$ is an increasing function. One way to prove this is to show its derivative is positive. Or just show the derivative of $x^{1/3}$ is positive without even worrying about $x^3$.

Comment: Careful, if you raise both sides by the power of 2 you can get a contradiction as $-2<1$ yet $4>1$ which would be the result of squaring which is a different case but could be worth pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct because taking the cube or taking the cube root are both monotonic.
Another way to see the result is by noting that (wrinting $u^3$ for $a$ and $v^3$ for $b$)
$$u^3-v^3 = (u-v)(u^2+uv+v^2)$$
where the second factor on the right is nonnegative: $u^2+uv+v^2=(u-v)^2+3uv\ge 0$ if $uv\ge0$ and also $u^2+uv+v^2=(u+v)^2-uv\ge 0$ if $uv<0$.

Comment: Your stated reason, "because taking the cube root is monotonic", is circular. The question is precisely whether the cube root is monotonic.  The rest of your answer is to the point.

Answer (score 1):

this true since the root functions are increasing. But just writing the power there doesn't prove anything.

Answer (score 1):

Given that:
$$b-a>0$$

$$(b^{1/3}-a^{1/3})(a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}+b^{1/3}a^{1/3})>0$$

Since $(a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}+b^{1/3}a^{1/3})>0$:

$$(b^{1/3}-a^{1/3})>0$$

Therefore, $b^{1/3}>a^{1/3}$.